# I Think This Is Getting Outdated But I Don't Care :)

Tags: riddle, wordplay

I really like these riddles so I'm gonna post another one

> With the beginning, you can put it on
>
> In the middle, you can tell others your position (Even if it's only a few letters long)
>
> While in the end, you might find yourself full
>
> My whole consists of just 4 letters

Comment: Clearly it's *SHIRTPHDFEAST*. Next :-)

Comment: Welp, I don't care either ;D

Comment: Lol. I saw your riley riddle so I decided to make one myself too :) @user477343

Comment: In the first line, "With the beginning you can put me on", does "me" refer to the word itself, or the prefix? (I think the "beginning" refers to the prefix, but I'm just clarifying.)

Comment: Yes it just refers to the prefix @user477343

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could it be

> hate?

With the beginning, you can put me on:

> hat

In the middle, you can tell others your position (Even if it's only a few letters long):

> at

While in the end, you may find yourself full:

> ate

My whole consists of just 4 letters:

> The word "hate" only has 4 letters.

If this isn't the answer, I think it should count as a correct one. :)

Comment: +1 Right on the spot! Which part gave it away?

Comment: Yaye! My first one solved as a new person to Puzzling. :)  I worked backwards from possibilities for the first and last. The first and last words were both in my first tier guesses for those hints.

Comment: Congratulations to your very first accepted answer on Puzzling! :D

Comment: Thanks @user477343! Finally! Feels great after banging my head against the wall on some of the truly obscure/bizarre ones.

Comment: I see... Well congrats anyways :) @Carley

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a stretch, but could it be a

> **CAPE**?

`With the beginning, you can put me on.`

> You can put on a **CAP**.

`In the middle, you can tell others your position (even if it's only a few letters long).`

> If you are a pilot in an **AP (aeroplane)**, you need to tell high authorities your position at a certain airport, I believe.

`While in the end, you may find yourself full.`

> While in the end of **PE (Physical Education)**, you may find yourself full **of sweat**.

`My whole consists of 4 letters.`

> **C** $\;$ **A** $\;$ **P** $\;$ **E**

Comment: I've never seen AP as an abbreviation for aeroplane.

Comment: @Randal'Thor yeah, I just made that up, hahah ;)

Comment: +1 Liked ur idea but not the one I had in mind :)